# GCC - "expected unqualified-id before ')' token"

Tags: c++

Please bear with me, I'm just learning C++.

I'm trying to write my header file (for class) and I'm running into an odd error.

```
cards.h:21: error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
cards.h:22: error: expected `)' before "str"
cards.h:23: error: expected `)' before "r"
```

What does "expected unqualified-id before ')' token" mean? And what am I doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry, I didn't post the entire code.

```
/*
Card header file
[Author]
*/
// NOTE: Lanugage Docs here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

#define Card
#define Hand
#define AppError

#include <string>

using namespace std;


// TODO: Docs here
class Card { // line 17
    public:
        enum Suit {Club, Diamond, Spade, Heart};
        enum Rank {Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine,
                   Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace};
        Card(); // line 22
        Card(string str);
        Card(Rank r, Suit s);
```

Edit: I'm just trying to compile the header file by itself using "g++ file.h".

Edit: Closed question. My code is working now. Thanks everyone!
Edit: Reopened question after reading [Etiquette: Closing your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456/etiquette-closing-your-posts)

Comment: Sorry, I will lookup #define rather than copying my professor's code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your issue is your `#define`. You did `#define Card`, so now everywhere `Card` is seen as a token, it will be replaced.

Usually a `#define Token` with no additional token, as in `#define Token Replace` will use the value `1`.

Remove the `#define Card`, it's making line 22 read: `1();` or `();`, which is causing the complaint.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. That makes sense now. I think I will do some reading in my book. The professor seems to be skipping details.

Answer (score 4):

(edited for updated question)

Remove the `#define` statements, they're mangling the file. Were you trying to implement an include guard? That would be something like this:

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

class Card ...
...

#endif
```

---

old answer:

It means that `string` is not defined in the current line. Try `std::string`.

Comment: And make sure that <string> is included.

Comment: I just edited the question to show the top of the file. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. I forgot to add the include guard.

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents, but I guess you used the pre-compiled header

```
#define Card
#define Hand
#define AppError
```

as if you wanted to tell the compiler "Hey, the classes Card, Hand and AppError are defined elsewhere" (i.e. forward-declarations).

Even if we ignore the fact macros are a pain for the exact reasons your code did not compile (as John Millikin put it, mangling your file), perhaps what you wanted to write was something like:

```
class Card ;
class Hand ;
class AppError ;
```

Which are *forward-declarations* of those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **#define Card**.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't show the entire file. The question has been edited.